# Desktop client inserting MySQL database-Now want to create a web service

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have developed an Ubuntu desktop application to monitor when computers are on that is currently writing directly to a MySQL database. For security purposes I assume that I don't want to have all of these clients talking directly to my database, and instead need to create some other web interface between the client and the database. Should I write this interface in PHP? How does the client invoke this interface?

Comment: Its perfectly valid to have your clients talking to your database its called 'client server' however you may want to talk through a webpage for other resons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For security purposes I assume that I don't want to have all of these clients talking directly to my database

Probably not. You can lock down the database to some degree, but probably not enough.

> instead need to create some other web interface between the client and the database.

Web services are the usual way to provide a controlled interface to a database these days.

> Should I write this interface in PHP?

You could. Language should is a fairly personal thing though. I'd probably go with Perl's [Dancer framework](http://www.perldancer.org/) myself. It is [capable of handling a RESTful API](http://advent.perldancer.org/2010/8) (although that guide assumes you've already learned the basics of Dancer).

> How does the client invoke this interface?

By making an HTTP request. It might be as simple as a POST request with `on` as the body (and then the server uses the client ip address to determine which machine the request came from). The specifics of how you go about that depend on the language you are writing the client in and the libraries you have available to it.